# SQL SELECT Join?

Tags: sql, mysql, select

I have a MySql DB.

There is a table with products and orders with the 
structure:

- Products: product_id, name, manufacturers_id
- Orders: orders_id, product_id, quantity

Now I want to get all orders (show only products where product manufacturers_id=1).
I tried:

```
SELECT
orders.orders_id,
orders.product_id
FROM products, orders
WHERE products.manufacturers_id = 1
GROUP BY orders_id
ORDER BY orders_id
```

But this doesn't work.  What's wrong?

Sry for editing: someone else edited my post end deleted an essentiell part of the question

**EDIT**

To clarify my problem I added some new information:

I got an MySQL DB with MyISAM tables. The two relevant tables are:

- orders_products: orders_products_id, orders_id, product_id, product_name, product_price, product_name, product_model, final_price, ...
- products: products_id, manufacturers_id, ...

(for full information about the tables see screenshot products ([Screenshot](http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/4585/producty.jpg)) and screenshot orders_products ([Screenshot](http://img188.imageshack.us/img188/3418/ordersproducts.jpg)))

Now what I want is this:
- Get all Orders who ordered products with manufacturers_id = 1. And the product name of the product of this order (with manufacturers_id = 1). Grouped by orders.

What I did so far is this:

```
SELECT
op.orders_id,
p.products_id,
op.products_name,
op.products_price,
op.products_quantity
FROM orders_products op , products p 
INNER JOIN products
ON op.products_id = p.products_id
WHERE p.manufacturers_id = 1 AND
p.orders_id > 10000
```

p.orders_id > 10000 for testing to get only a few order_id's.
But thies query takes much time to get executed if it even works.
Two times the sql server stucked. 
Where is the mistake?

Because of the confusing about my edits i opened a new more understandable post:
[SQL Inner Join : DB stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484518/sql-inner-join-db-stuck)

Comment: You say "product_id=1, but your query says manufacturers_id = 1...need clarification on which is correct

Comment: What error are you getting? n your code you are using manufacturers_id = 1 rather than product_id = 1 in the where clause. Is this a misprint, because you state in your question that you want to limit by product_id = 1?

Comment: Sorry for the error in the post.
I want all orders with the products where products.manufacturers_id =1 . 
But the manufacturers_id is in the table products

Comment: @SurfingCat: Doesn't my answer reply your question?

Answer (score 2):

That should do it!

```
SELECT
*.orders
FROM orders INNER JOIN products
ON orders.product_id = products.product_id
WHERE products.manufacturers_id =1
ORDER BY orders_id
```

Comment: I totally do not see where you get the "AND products.manufacturers_id = 38 " from

Comment: LOL, the user updated it. It used to be 38 just a few minutes ago. I just updated mine accordingly, as it looked wrong now :-)

Comment: Great, I use the EDIT: form when I update my question, makes this kind of thing more reasonable.

Comment: I added some information to my post. I think this is the right way but to slow and i don't know why :-/

Answer (score 1):

The simple way would be:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE product_id = 1
```

Comment: +1: For the given query statement, the join is unnecessary.  Obviously, if the output needed the manufacturer or something, then the join would be needed - but not as stated.

Comment: I need all products and order id where products.manufacturers_id = 1

Comment: @SurfingCat, ok, but that is not what your original question said ;-)

Answer (score 0):

WHERE products.manufacturers_id = 1 AND products.product_id = orders.product_id

That's if you want to join the two tables. And besides that you request a **product_od** instead of a **product_id**