# SQL Inner Join : DB stuck

Tags: sql, mysql, join, myisam

I postet this question a few days ago but I didn't explain exactly what I want. 
I ask the question better formulated again:
To clarify my problem I added some new information:

I got an MySQL DB with MyISAM tables. The two relevant tables are:

```
* orders_products: orders_products_id, orders_id, product_id, product_name, product_price, product_name, product_model, final_price, ...
* products: products_id, manufacturers_id, ...
```

(for full information about the tables see screenshot products ([Screenshot](http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/4585/producty.jpg)) and screenshot orders_products ([Screenshot](http://img188.imageshack.us/img188/3418/ordersproducts.jpg)))

Now what I want is this: - Get all Orders who ordered products with manufacturers_id = 1. And the product name of the product of this order (with manufacturers_id = 1). Grouped by orders.

What I did so far is this:

```
SELECT
op.orders_id,
p.products_id,
op.products_name,
op.products_price,
op.products_quantity
FROM orders_products op , products p 
INNER JOIN products
ON op.products_id = p.products_id
WHERE p.manufacturers_id = 1 AND
p.orders_id > 10000
```

p.orders_id > 10000 for testing to get only a few order_id's. But thies query takes much time to get executed if it even works. Two times the sql server stucked. Where is the mistake?

Comment: The little colored diamonds mean nothing to anyone that doesn't know that tool. The exact DDL statements would be better to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
op.orders_id, 
p.products_id, 
op.products_name, 
op.products_price, 
op.products_quantity 
FROM orders_products op   
INNER JOIN products p
ON op.products_id = p.products_id 
WHERE p.manufacturers_id = 1 AND 
p.orders_id > 10000
```

YOu had both implicit and explict joins on the products table (Make a note to never again use the implicit join syntax, it is a very bad programmin practice) and looking at the code, I suspect you were getting a cross join.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have any indexes then the select may be generating many table scans.

It may be that you are getting back a very large result set, that could fill up the temp area, which could explain getting stuck.